# Is it possible to hack the lisp reader to "allow" lists with dots in them?

Tags: common-lisp

Is it possible to get the following behavior? If I read `'(a . b . c)` from the standard input I want the lisp `read` function to produce the same as `(list (intern "A") (intern ".") (intern "B") (intern ".") (intern "C"))`.

Currently, it (SBCL) triggers a parsing error telling that a list can't start with a dot, or that dot can't be used multiple times, which is perfectly normal. However, I am wondering if it would be possible to catch the `SIMPLE-READER-ERROR` on the fly and tweak the stream accordingly.

I am able to catch the error and install a restart however I have no idea how to tweak the stream on the fly. Is it possible?

Comment: you would best need to create a new readtable (copy the original) and then redefine the reader macro to read lists.

Comment: Yes, this looks like the best method. I tried to hot-patch `COMMON-LISP:READ-CHAR` but this does not work well since SBCL is using an internal buffer to speed-up things which bypasses `READ-CHAR`. So redefining the reader macro to read lists seems to effectively be the best and most conformant way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: this is run in Emacs Lisp (`M-x ielm`), don't know if it works somewhere else.

When I enter

```
(list (intern "A") (intern ".") (intern "B") (intern ".") (intern "C"))
```

this gives as a result

```
(A \. B \. C)
```

So, using this "suggestion", I can enter without any error:

```
'(A \. B \. C)
```

Comment: SBCL accepts it and says `(A |.| B |.| C)`

Comment: This is nice but I really need to have only `.` and no escaping whatsoever.